# deploying symfony 3 with cPanel

Tags: symfony, deployment, cpanel, backend

I have some troubles deploying a **Symfony 3 app** in cPanel.
I had no problems deploying in Heroku or Fortrabbit.

The problem is :

> I can't connect to my backend using example.com or example.com/app.php
>   from my frontend and I have to use example.com/app_dev.php.

This only works because I commented these lines in my backend's app_dev.php:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1']) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

But I don't think this is the right way to do it.

> Is there anyway to set SYMFONY_ENV=prod in cPanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't. That's on the feature request list:

https://features.cpanel.net/topic/setenv-for-addon-domains-and-subdomains

You could try to edit the .bash_profile file on your cPanel account (if you have ssh access you can do it via ssh, if not you can use FileManager from cPanel and try to add something like this:

```
export SYMFONY_ENV=prod
```

Then try again.

**UPDATE:**

That file is usually found in `/home/cpanelusername/.bash_profile`

Comment: thank you, but where can I find that file? I'm really new to cPanel

Comment: that path doesn't exist in my cPanel :/

Comment: Did you replace cpanelusername with your actual cpanel user? Keep in mind that you should enable "Show Hidden Files" in cPanel File Manager to be able to display files starting with `.`

Comment: I haven't change anything, I'm just using the default configuration and I can't find the way to show hidden files. I'm using heliohost btw.

Comment: oh, nvm, I found it! now I will try to set it as you said

Comment: Do I have to do something else after editing .bash_profile file? because it didn't work

Comment: Try reading this, maybe it helps... https://www.geekstorage.com/blog/index.php/setup-symfony-on-cpanel-shared